# MAC IOS IPC: how to write P2P applications in MAC and IOS?

Tags: objective-c, macos, ios4

I'm looking for a way to communicate between a MAC application and an IOS one. Communication should be peer to peer, as IOS application shoul dbe able to send requests to MAC app and the other way around.
I'd be grateful for any hints you might have.

Cheers,

Andrea

Answer (score 1):

Apple Bonjour is the way to go:
[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonjour_(software)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonjour_%28software%29)
http://www.mobileorchard.com/tutorial-networking-and-bonjour-on-iphone/

Especially the sample project from the last link might be useful.

Comment: Many thanks Anne for the pointers, I really appreciate your help